# How Campaigns works in chartboost in android?

Tags: android

Help me in Campaigns and More apps setting in Chart-Boost and how can it be implemented in android.
i am trying to implement it but it gives the following exception.

```
Chartboost:  Exception on http request: Request aborted
```

Comment: i take help from the following example: https://github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples        these example help me realy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely recommend checking out the example project it's really help and located at https://github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples

Also, you want to make sure you have a campaign set up (Campaigns -> Add Campaign -> Publish in network). I would also make your device a test device so that it can see every ad possible (check out http://help.chartboost.com/faq/general#test)

Also, email support@chartboost.com they're pretty cool and try their best to help out